# cellophane bags

Tags: polymers

I am conducting an experiment to test the components of a cello bag. I believe that cello bags do not just contain cellulose, and as mentioned by many websites, only 92-98%, but not 100% of the bag is cellulose.

What do you think the bag is made up of?

Answer (score 1):

Hydrophilic materials always contain small amount of moisture.  Cotton fibers are not 100% cellulose either. In cello bags, there may be residual chemicals from viscose process and speculatively some modifiers.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellophane) says there are used softeners like glycerine to prevent brittleness.